# Communities - Able to access Visualforce page without authentication

Tags: visualforce, community

I have a customer community and added a visualforce page to the community by going to **Sites** then **Site Visualforce Pages**. I am able to invoke the VF page by directly going to **CommunityURL/vfpage** and I was surprised with this behavior and I thought Salesforce would redirect the user to login page but It did not and able to access the page without authentication.

Just to give more info, If I go to **CommunityURL** and it would redirect me to login page but If I open VFpage directly , no login is required.

I also tested this by opening the browser in incognito mode just to make sure my login is not cached but same behavior.

Can you please give me some insight why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Setup -> Communities -> All Communities -> click Manage -> Administration -> Pages -> Go to force.com -> Click on public access settings.

This shows you a profile page that has visualforce pages with public access. If you removed your page from there it will be only available in authenticated context.

Comment: Thanks but If I remove the page as you mentioned, the community will not have access to the page at all. I want the community to access the page only after authentication.

Comment: Public access settings is for public pages ... You can still assign the page to community user profile and as community page.  This will make it protected